# Pick a Single Row Out of Each Set of Duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Mock up table:**

[image]

I need to eliminate duplicate records from the first table. In case we have duplicate address_num such as 100, we will go with the row of AddressType "Home".

Please note that address_num do not come in duplicates of 3 or more; they either appear once or twice in a table. For example, address_num 200 appeared once. Therefore, we just grabbed it as is.

ID column is the primary key.

The second table with the right check mark is the results table. How can I write an oracle SQL query that prints out the second table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()` and an intelligent use of `order by`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by address_num
                                order by (case when AddressType = 'Home' then 1 else 0 end) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT id, address_num, ...
FROM (
    SELECT id, address_num, ...
         , row_number() over (partition by address_num
                              order by addresstype) as rn
    FROM T
) AS X
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Select only those rows with the lowest Id within each set of Dupes.

```
 Select * From MockUpTable m
 Where Id = 
     (Select Min(id)
      From MockUpTable
      Where address_num = m.address_num)
```